# Alert class based on it's length with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, class

So basically I'm trying to select the class "on" only, but based on the class length of 2.

```
<div class="film cars-0317219 on"></div>
<div class="film wall-e-0910970 on"></div>
<div class="film off up-0945232"></div>
<div class="film on finding-nemo-0266543"></div>
<div class="film off cars-0317219"></div>
```

Something like:

```
$('div.film').live('click', function(){
var classes=$(this).attr("class").split(" ");
var status=classes[classes.length=2];

alert(status);
});
```

Should alert "on"

Any idea how to get the alert based on the string length? (Likewise, if I put 3 instead of 2 in the code, it should alert "off")

Comment: and it's not just `on` you want to get?  If there also happened to be a class `ok` you'd want to get that too? (based on getting all of length==2)

Comment: You absolutely must test based on length?  `$(this).hasClass("on")` is out of the question?

Comment: @rockerest Yes, it's just based on length.

Comment: @Stephen length==2 alerts undefined for some reason instead of on. Also, if it's class ok I want to get that too.

Comment: @Maverick - I wasn't providing syntax, just asking for clarification. I wouldn't expect `length==2` to work without some context, which I also didn't provide.

Comment: @Stephen, sorry about the misunderstanding there. I hope I clarified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do:

```
alert(classes[1]);
```

arrays in javascript are zero based and so the second element has an index of 1 (and the third element has an index of 2)

EDIT - now i understand the OP means the length of the word on (2 letters):

```
var classes=$(this).attr("class").split(" ");
for (i = 0; i<classes.length; i++){
   if (classes[i].length ===2){
      alert(classes[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: on or ok can be anywhere in the class attribute, so I need to make sure to grab it based on it's length and alert it

Answer (score 2):

```
var status=classes[1]; // the second element of the array
```

---

#### Better way to do what you want to do:

```
var isOn=$('.film').hasClass('on');

alert(isOn?'on':'off');
```

Remember that `$('.film')` will only get the 1st element with that class when perform these types of operations unless this is in a handler like `click` in which case you would use `$(this)`

Comment: Updated code, but it can be any two letter, so it should only be based on length

Comment: @Mavrick -- what do you mean `any two letter`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to alert only classes of a certain length, you can proceed like this

```
a=['film', 'cars-0317219', 'on'];//same as your var classes;
var status = a.filter(function(x){
 return x.length==this.size;
},{size:2});//contains ['on']
```

However filter is implemented for firefox, I don't know for other browsers.

Comment: I need to make sure it's cross browser

Answer (score 0):

```
function something(){
var classSplitOn =" ";
var desiredCount = 2;

var onClassSelector = ".on";

$('.film').each(function(index,elem){
  var classString = elem.className;
  if(classString && classString.split(classSplitOn).length == desiredCount){
    var alertVal = "off";
    if($(this).is(onClassSelector)){
      alertVal = "on";
    }
    alert(alertVal);
  }
});
}
```

Comment: you would want to pass my function into your .live() declaration.  you can even start playing with passing it data, possibly the three variables i set on top.

Comment: did you want it to fire on Each 'has X # of classes, and is on'  per click?  or just evaluate the current element clicked?